# Rango números en javascript

Tags: javascript

Tengo el siguiente objetivo: Escribe un programa que solicite dos números, Si el primer número es menor que el segundo,  imprime los números en el rango de forma ascendente. 
Por ejemplo, si el usuario ingresa 5 como primer número y 10 como segundo número, el programa debe imprimir: 5,6,7,8,9,10, pero si no debe imprimirlos en forma descendente. 10,9,8,7,6,5. Mi código es el siguiente:

```js
var num1 = parseInt(prompt("Ingrese un numero: "));
var num2 = parseInt(prompt("Ingrese otro numero: "));


for(let i = 0; i<=num1; i=i+1){
    if (num1 < num2){
        document.write(num1[i]);
    }if (num1 > num2){
        document.write(num2[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: deberías tener un for para cada caso dentro de cada condición

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Una solución podría ser la siguiente:

- Determinamos cual de los valores ingresados es el menor/mayor.
- Generamos un arreglo que contenga los valores en el rango.
- Si el primer valor ingresado es mayor al segundo, invertimos el arreglo.

#### Ejemplo:

```js
var num1 = parseInt(prompt("Ingrese un numero: "));
var num2 = parseInt(prompt("Ingrese otro numero: "));

let min = Math.min(num1, num2);
let max = Math.max(num1, num2);
let output = Array.from({length: max - min + 1}, (v, i) => i + min);
if (num1 > num2) output.reverse();
console.log(output.join(','));
```

#### Referencias:

[`Math.max`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Math/max), [`Math.min`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Math/min), [`Array.form`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/from), [`Array.reverse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/reverse), [`Array.join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/join)

Answer (score 3):

Te enlistare las fallas de tu código.

1. primero deberías hacer la validación de que numero es mayor y después hacer el ciclo for.
2. El valor de i debe ser igual a num1.
3. Es imposible que imprimas num1[x] o num2[x] ya que ninguno es un array, objeto  o string.

Tomando en cuenta eso el código debería quedar algo asi.

```js
var num1 = parseInt(prompt("Ingrese un numero: "));
var num2 = parseInt(prompt("Ingrese otro numero: "));

if (num1 <= num2){
   for(let i = num1; i<=num2; i++){
        document.write(i);
   }
}
else{
    for(let i = num1; i>=num2; i--){
        document.write(i);
   }
}
```

Este código no es la única manera de hacerlo, me base en lo que ya tenías y le hice los cambios que te enliste arriba, Saludos.

Comment: muy bien explicado, pero que pasa cuando el  valor minimo y maximo es el mismo; obviendo este caso excelente respuesta

Comment: excelente apunte, ya hice la corrección para incluis este caso.

Answer (score 1):

Como dice Christian, deberías tener un for para cada caso dentro de cada condición asi:

```js
var num1 = parseInt(prompt("Ingrese un numero: "));
var num2 = parseInt(prompt("Ingrese otro numero: "));

if (num1 < num2){
    for(let i = num1; i<=num2; i++){    
        document.write(i);
    }
}
if (num1 > num2){
    for(let i = num1; i>=num2; i--){    
        document.write(i);
    }
}
```